# Superposition of two renewal processes

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Usually, superposition of two independent renewal processes may not lead to a renewal process. However, in my problem, the interval time between two events of the renewal process is more specific which follows a time shift exponential distribution.

To be more specific, now I have two renewal processes whose average rates are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. The density functions of the interval time $T_1$ and $T_2$ are $\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1(t-\beta_1)}$ and  $\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2(t-\beta_2)}$.

I was wondering after the superposition, if it is possible to derive a closed form of the average rate and variance of the new/synthesized process.

Comment: The distribution of the numbers $N_i(t)$ of arrivals on an interval
$(0, t)$ can be computed numerically for each process $i=1$, $2$. See
[this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87223/variance-of-arrival-process-with-shifted-exponential-distribution)

Comment: Thanks @Yves. I have found that question before. However, I am more interested in the distribution of the numbers $N_1(t) + N_2(t)$ of arrivals. I think the memoryless property does not hold true in my problem so I cannot simply add the two rates together.

Comment: If the two processes can be thought of as being independent, then the
two r.vs $N_1(t)$ are $N_2(t)$ are independent, the memoryless
property not impacting this. So you can compute the variance of the
sum $N_1(t) + N_2(t)$ and even its distribution by convolution. Note
that 'rate' is ambiguous since the arrival rate of process $i$ is not
$\lambda_i$.